# Google Maps Action Bar

Tags: android, google-maps, responsive-design, android-actionbar-compat

I've already searched for hours but I still can't find answer on how to implement an action bar like google maps which is responsive to touch? Even if the user scrolls on top of the action bar, the map still scrolls. Please please.

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.view.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="560dp"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/disclaimer_container">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:id="@+id/ulo">
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/facility_map"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/facility_map_dummy"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/dummy"
                    android:alpha="0.3" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            <include
                android:id="@+id/content"
                layout="@layout/activity_establishment_details">
            </include>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.view.ObservableScrollView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_facility"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/disclaimer_container"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="To ensure ease and convenience of your medical availment, please proceed to the physician coordinator’s clinic, Industrial Department, or the HMO Office first. Your physician coordinator will refer you to the appropriate specialist."
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="180dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/doctor_map2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/dummy"
                android:background="@drawable/dummy"
                android:alpha="0.7" />
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/up"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/action_green"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_up" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facility_details);
    initLayout();
    context = this;
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_facility);
    mActionBarBackgroundDrawable = mToolbar.getBackground();

    dc = new DataCollection(FacilityDetailActivity.this);

    previousDrawable = mToolbar.getBackground();
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mToolbar.setPadding(0, Globals.getStatusBarHeight(this), 0, 0);
    // create our manager instance after the content view is set
    SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
    // enable status bar tint
    tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
    // enable navigation bar tint
    tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
    // set the transparent color of the status bar, 20% darker
    tintManager.setTintColor(Color.parseColor("#20000000"));

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" ");

    mStatusBarManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
    mStatusBarManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
    mInitialStatusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.main_color_dark);
    mFinalStatusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(FacilityDetailActivity.this, R.color.main_color_dark);
    report_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.report_error);
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

    mHeader = findViewById(R.id.facility_map);

    report_error.setVisibility(Globals.ACTIVATE_REPORT_ERROR ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    ObservableScrollable scrollView = (ObservableScrollable) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    scrollView.setOnScrollChangedCallback(this);

    onScroll(-1, 0);
    initValues();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    slidingPane = (SlidingUpPanelLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
    slidingPane.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN);
    fab =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.up);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            slidingPane.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN);
        }
    });

    report_error.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FacilityDetailActivity.this, ReportErrorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        float elevation = 4 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        mToolbar.setElevation(elevation);
    }

}
```

This is the method for setting up the map

```
 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.facility_map))
                .getMap();
        mMap2 = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.doctor_map2))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
            setUpMap2();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            slidingPane.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);
        }
    });
    LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(facility.getLatitude(),facility.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinates);
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13);
    mMap.moveCamera(center);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(coordinates)
            .title(facility.getName())
            .snippet(facility.getAddress() + ", " + facility.getCityName() + ", "
                    + facility.getProvinceName())
            .icon(CustomBitmapPin.getCorrespondingMapPinForFacility(this, facility))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));

    final ScrollView mainLayout = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    final ImageView dummy = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facility_map_dummy);
    dummy.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    mainLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    // Disable touch on transparent view
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    mainLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mainLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;

                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have already tried this but it still has no effect

```
    mToolbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mToolbar.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mToolbar.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mToolbar.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;

                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: @Vini I have tried using "        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);" but to no effect. I have also searched for hours but there seems to be no answer to my problem. :(

Comment: I already posted my code @AnswerDroid

Comment: Did you get the actionBar shown? You can also use the new `toolbar` instead of `ActionBar`.

Comment: I am using the new toolbar as the actionbar. And yes, the transparent toolbar is shown but it is hindering the navigation on the upper part of the map. @bjiang